# How does Angular do automatic change detection for collection-level change?

Tags: angular

I think Angular doesn’t detect collection level data change(e.g when a new element is added to an array)
But in my case,  Angular did detect collection level change in my case, which I don't know why it does it. Below is my code:

```
// TableComponent's template

<tr *ngFor="let item of getProducts()">
   ...
</tr>
```

and the component is sth like:

```
export class TableComponent {

    constructor(private model: Model) { }  // model is injected

    getProducts(): Product[] {
        return this.model.getProducts();
    }
    ...
}
```

and another component manages to add a product by calling `submitForm` as:

```
export class FormComponent {
    product: Product = new Product();

    constructor(private model: Model) { }  // model is injected

    submitForm(form: NgForm) {
        if (form.valid) {
            this.model.saveProduct(this.product);
            this.product = new Product();
            form.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

So when I add a new product on the form, I expect the table won't automatically add the new product to the view as `getProducts()` in `<tr *ngFor="let item of getProducts()">` return an array of products, when a new product is added to the array collection, the angular should not automatically detect it, but why in my case I can still see the table automatically changes(a new row is inserted) to reflect a new product is added?

Answer (score 1):

I need to see the entire component of the HTML template where you use the ngFor.

Is it possible that you are using something like:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

Comment: no, I didn't use it, actually the source code is here:   https://github.com/Apress/pro-angular-9/blob/master/24%20-%20Making%20HTTP%20Requests/End%20of%20Chapter/exampleApp/src/app/core/form.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to bind your html to a function, like you did with `getProducts()` here:  `*ngFor="let item of getProducts()"`
The reason for this is that angular cannot detect whether a function has changed or not, so it must re-run the function every time.

The better way to do it is to have some sort of property, ex products, and do something like `product = this.getProducts()`, or even cut out the middleman and have `product = this.model.getProducts();`. Then, in your HTML bind to `products`. This will improve performance, as well as prevent the detection of changes.

so, to summarize, change your code to this:

ts:

```
products: Product[];
...
this.products= this.model.getProducts();
```

HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of products">
```

Comment: but Angualr is still not be able to automatically detect a change in a array(e.g append a new product to the product array,) so no a new table row will be added , but why in my case, a new table row is added?

Comment: in your case, the detection *is* run - since anything that happens (click, hover, etc) causes the change detection to run. Since change detection cannot tell if a function has changed or not, it **always** recalls the function. So your `getProducts()` is called again, and it shows the change